# Point color in gnuplot 4.0

Tags: gnuplot

When I try to plot three separate data files using gnuplot, I get an error "';' expected" in the output when I try to change the point color of the data sets.

For example, this works fine:

```
set terminal jpeg size 900,500
set xlabel 'x axis label'
set ylabel 'y axis label'
set title 'sample title'
set output "output.jpeg"
set xrange [-0.1:1.1]
set yrange [] reverse
set xtics 0.10
#set ytics 100
set key top left
set grid ytics lt 0 lw 1
set grid xtics lt 0 lw 1

plot 'file1.dat' u 1:2 w p pt 7 ps 0.8 ti 'dataset 1', \
     'file2.dat' u 1:2 w p pt 6 ps 0.8 ti 'dataset 2', \
     'file3.dat' u 1:2 w p pt 5 ps 0.8 ti 'dataset 3'
```

This does not:

```
set terminal jpeg size 900,500
set xlabel 'x axis label'
set ylabel 'y axis label'
set title 'sample title'
set output "output.jpeg"
set xrange [-0.1:1.1]
set yrange [] reverse
set xtics 0.10
#set ytics 100
set key top left
set grid ytics lt 0 lw 1
set grid xtics lt 0 lw 1

plot 'file1.dat' u 1:2 w p pt 7 ps 0.8 lc 9 ti 'dataset 1', \
     'file2.dat' u 1:2 w p pt 6 ps 0.8 ti 'dataset 2', \
     'file3.dat' u 1:2 w p pt 5 ps 0.8 ti 'dataset 3'
```

Why is this? Is there a workaround to simply change point color independent of point style and size?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell me what gnuplot version you use. I tried your sample code on `gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 1` and works fine. 
@NeelBhatt Vote up.

Comment: gnuplot 4.0 patch level 0

Comment: The 4.0 version was released in 2004. Please try to install a newer version.

Comment: Side note: JPEG is the worst choice of all possible output formats. JPEG is meant for photorealistic pictures and nothing else. Consider using a vector format or something like PNG if you really require raster images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `linecolor` (`lc`) was introduced in version 4.2. In your case you can change the color using `linetype` (`lt`):

```
set terminal jpeg size 900,500
set output "output.jpeg"
plot 'file1.dat' u 1:2 w p pt 7 ps 0.8 lt 9 ti 'dataset 1'
```

But I also strongly recommend you to upgrade!